# Model not getting bound to the view in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am trying to display a list of Providers in a table.The code to get the list of providers is as follows

```
     public ActionResult Index()
    {
        DAL2 dal = new DAL2();
        Provider patientlist = new Provider();
        List<Provider> providers = dal.GetListofProviders.ToList();
        return View(providers);
    }
```

The above code is working fine.I am getting the list of providers as expected.

The HTML code in the view is as follows

```
  @model IEnumerable<ProviderDemo.Models.Provider>

  @{
     ViewBag.Title = "ProviderList";
   }
  <head>
     <title>LIST OF PROVIDERS</title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
         <tr>     
           <th>Provider Type</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Certification</th>
             <th>Specialization</th>
              <th>SSN</th>
              <th>Facility Name</th>
              <th>Contact No</th>
             <th>Contact Email</th>
              <th></th>  
        </tr>  
              <tbody data-bind="foreach: viewmodel">
            <tr>
              <td class="col-lg-2" data-bind="text: ProviderType"></td>
              <td class="col-lg-1" data-bind="text: FirstName"></td>
              <td class="col-lg-1" data-bind="text: LastName"></td>
              <td class="col-lg-1" data-bind="text: Certification"></>
              <td class="col-lg-1" data-bind="text: Specialization"></td>
              <td class="col-lg-1" data-bind="text: SSN"></td>
              <td class="col-lg-4" data-bind="text: FacilityName"></td>
              <td class="col-lg-4" data-bind="text: ContactNumber"></td>
              <td class="col-lg-1" data-bind="text: ContactEmail"></td>
              <td><a class="btn btn-default" id="del" onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure, you want to delete');" data-bind="attr: { href: '/ProviderRegister/Delete/' + ProviderID }"> Delete        </a>
              </td>
          </tr> 
      </tbody>           
    </table>
     </body>
```

My Provider class is as follows:

```
  public class Provider
{
    public int    ProviderID { get; set; }
    public string ProviderType { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Certification { get; set; }
    public string Specialization { get; set; }
    public string SSN { get; set; }
    public string ContactNumber { get; set; }
    public string ContactEmail { get; set; }
    public string FacilityName { get; set; }
}
```

Provider Viewmodel

```
  var Provider =
          {
              ProviderID:ko.observable(""),
              ProviderType: ko.observable(""),
              FirstName: ko.observable(""),
              LastName: ko.observable(""),
              Certification: ko.observable(""),
              Specialization: ko.observable(""),
              SSN: ko.observable(""),
              ContactNumber: ko.observable(""),
              ContactEmail: ko.observable(""),
              FacilityName: ko.observable(""),
          }
            ko.applyBindings(Provider);
```

The list is not getting displayed in the table.There seems to be an error at the top of the html for the model.I dont understand why though.Am I doing something wrong here?Please guide me in the right direction.

Thanks a lot for all your help guys,but I made a mistake earlier.In the Index action ,I see the list of providers but I dont get any data in the view.So,I have the data in the controller but not in the view.

Comment: Try `<tbody data-bind="foreach: $data">`. Also, show your Knockout model-binding code.

Comment: Wouldn't mentioning the model at the top bind the table data to the  model.I am getting a squiggly atthe model declaration.I thought that was where the issue was.

Comment: You are mixing up server and client-side binding. Your knockout code has no concept of - or access to - the model of your MVC view because that model does not exist any more when your JavaScript runs - it only exists when your Razor is being rendered *on the server*. You need to render those model values out somewhere and write some JavaScript to pick them up and bind them to your knockout model (or render them directly into your KO script block, or fetch them via AJAX, or...).

Comment: If you have decided to go with SPA, then this is not the way to do it.. follow the Ant P's approach

Comment: How do I fetch them using AJAX>Could you please guide me on the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a populated Model, you need to get the data from that out into you knockout model. So either use `System.Web.Helpers.Json.Encode()` or make your own JSON in the view.

Then load that data into your knockout view model.

```
var data = @Json.Encode(Model);

var ViewModel = function(data) {
    var self = this;

    self.Providers = ko.observableArray(data);
};

var viewmodel = new ViewModel(data);
ko.applyBindings(viewmodel);
```

and then in your foreach, use Providers instead of viewmodel

Comment: Can i write the above code within the view or should I write it in Separate Javascript file.Sorry if this is a noob question but I am learning knockout and MVC.

Comment: @AbhishekKS To be honest it sounds like you've bitten off more than you can chew and you need to learn one thing at a time until you understand things well enough to see how they fit together.

Comment: I agree.My company has asked us to create a Dempapp using Bootstrap,Knpckout and MVC.Hence the predicament. :)

Comment: @AbhishekKS To answer your question - since there is razor in this JavaScript, it would have to go in your view. If you want it in a separate JS file, you will have to render the serialized model to the DOM somewhere and pick it up from there in your JS. Personally I would prefer to do the latter as embedding Razor in JS gets very confusing very quickly since the Razor runs on the server to generate different bits of the JS which runs on the client.